# Can I charge the seeker missile without wasting a missile in Metroid Prime 3?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption, metroid-prime-trilogy

In order to lock on to targets with the seeker missile in *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption*, I have to press and hold the down button on the D-Pad. However doing so fires a single missile, which is wasted. With only ~100 missiles this can be a big waste! Is theer a way to charge up the seeker missiles and lock on to targets without wasting this first missile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you fire a regular beam charge shot and then immediately hold down the missile button, you should be able to start charging the seeker missile without having to "waste" a shot.

The key is to begin holding down the missile button during the "cooldown" period of the charge shot animation (when you are unable to fire anything, beam *or* missile).

Answer (score 2):

Go into Scan Visor. Press and hold d-pad down. While holding d-pad down, tap (A) to return to Combat Visor. You are now in Seeker missile lock-on mode without having fired a missile.